# Windows Explorer hangs when opening a specific folder

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, ntfs, freeze

When I open a particular folder on my inside a folder on my desktop.  This folder was copied via a DVD-ROM from a previous computer.  I didn't have any problems with this folder on the other computer.  There are 36,316 files and 7,558 folders in this directory and it's 3.30GB.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: >36,316 files. That might be it, that's quite a lot :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe I didn't notice this.  There were shortcuts in the root folder that referenced my old computer.  They had absolute paths.  They changed from C:\ to \\old-computer\c$.  I'm on a enterprise network if that has anything to do with it.

I removed those shortcuts and reinstalled Windows.  All is well now.

Answer (score 0):

Did the old computer have better hardware?

It is likely XP indexing the folder and trying to gather information about the subfolders. If there are a lot of images in the parent folder, explorer will typically hang as there are so many thumbnails to generate.

The hiccup would be much more noticeable on older hardware.

Comment: nope, I went from Pentium D to a Core2.

Answer (score 0):

Is anything appearing in Task Manager with high CPU usage at all?

Do you have any antivirus software running?  If so, depending on the type of files, it may well be trying to scan the behemoth of a folder in the background.  This could be resulting in the lockup.

If so, try temporarily disabling it to see if it helps.

Answer (score -2):

This also happened to me but mine was different. I couldn't open a sub folder in one of my drive which was full of softwares. I opened the my computer from xyplorer. I realized that the folder was shared. So I unshared it and then I was able to open it from widows explorer. You can try any explorer to try this if your problem is not solved.

Comment: He already explained what the issue was. You already realized yourself that your issue differs from this one. -1 because I don't think this answer contributes to this question.